# Is there a 'proper' way to avoid 'must be final' error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I want to write a loop like this:

```
ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < THREADS_TOTAL; i++) {
    threads.add(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            foo(i);
        }
    });
    // more code
}
```

but I get a compiler error

> Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or
> effectively final.

Is there a way to circumvent this error, especially when the variable in question is a primitive type, and the anonymous class should't see the changes anyway? The options that I've considered are:

1. Defining a named class outside the loop and passing `i` into the constructor. I don't like this option, because it creates unnecessary indirection, and furthermore this is in a context of creating unit tests, so I would end up with a lot of additional inner classes, one for each such case.
2. Using IntStream, forEach and lambdas. This doesn't work well, because of `// more code`.
3. Creating another variable, like `int j = i;` inside the loop and using `j` inside the anonymous class. This seems like the most 'clean' option so far, but I still don't like it, because this line would serve no semantic purpose, it'd only be there to appease the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward IMO is:

```
ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < THREADS_TOTAL; i++) {
    final int good_name = i;
    threads.add(new Thread(() -> foo(good_name)));
    // more code
}
```

Short and directly to the point.